# Get download url from hockey after deploy with fastlane

Tags: ios, slack-api, fastlane

I am now using fastlane and I can post to slack like this.

```
version = get_version_number(xcodeproj: "***")

slack(
  message: "<!here|here>: New :ios: *#{version}* has been submitted to Dev Hockey :rocket:.",
)
```

In terminal, I saw something like this after deployment is finished. How can I get  get that url and post automatically to slack?

> [15:35:04]: Public Download URL:
>   https://upload.hockeyapp.net/apps/52da8f2b3da60cf8b6d4eaas5f06ae9b

I am reading about their code and they are printing to terminal something like this. But, I don't know how to retrieve and post to slack.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/hockey.rb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Khant Thu Linn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1550974/khant-thu-linn) you found a good snippet. 
In the fastlane docs you can see [all context variables](https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#lane-context).
To get the hockey app download link use

```
lane_context[SharedValues::HOCKEY_DOWNLOAD_LINK]
```

which will be generated by `hockey`.

This could be an example Slack call for your fastfile:

```
slack(
    message: "New :ios: version has been submitted to Hockey :rocket:.",
    payload: {  
        "Hockey App Download URL" => lane_context[SharedValues::HOCKEY_DOWNLOAD_LINK] 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to post hockey download url to slack from this link.

http://rolandleth.com/fastlane-fastfile-3

```
  slack_params = {
    message: 'iOS App successfully released to Hockey!',
    payload: {
      # 'Date' => "#{t.year}-#{t.month}-#{t.day} #{t.hour}:#{t.min} (#{t.zone})",
      # Because we increase the version after each build,
      # but submit before the increase
      'Build' => "#{build_number.to_i - 1}",
      'Version' => version_number,
      'Type' => type
    },
    default_payloads: [:git_branch, :git_author, :last_git_commit]
  }

  if release_lane lane
    slack_params[:message] = 'iOS App successfully submitted to the App Store!'

    commit_tag_and_update_release_branch
  else
    slack_params[:payload]['Download Link'] = "#{Actions.lane_context[Actions::SharedValues::HOCKEY_DOWNLOAD_LINK]}"
  end

  slack slack_params
```